# Why would I get this webpack and babel error for every javascript file in my solution?

Tags: json, npm, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am using Webpack 5.73 and Babel-loader 8.2.5.

My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "text-loader": "^0.0.1",
```

In my webpack.config.js file, I am using babel like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        //Use babel to translate ES2015+ to a more compatible version of JS
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "Game"),
            exclude: /(Game\/lib|userFiles)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    //Processed in reverse order
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    //cacheDirectory: true
                }
            }
        },
                    {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff2?|svg)$/,
            type: 'asset'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource'
        },
```

However, when running `npm run webpack`, for every .js file in my project, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./Game/gameViews/MainView.js 4:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'text' in 'G:\GameHub\Project\Game\gameViews'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'text-loader' instead of 'text',
```

I tried deleting my package.lock.json and node_modules then reinstalling everything again but I keep getting the errors every time I run webpack.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any other loader you added? share required Webpack details. Cant judge with this much code.

Comment: @MORÈ no, but I think I might need the `text-loader`?